# Laravel remote database select: quick in tinker, slow in view (30 second delay)?

Tags: laravel

I have a remote database (SQL Server, read-only) used for my `Test` model,
and a local SQLite database used for e.g. `User` model.
Using Laravel 8.12.

The `Test` model defines the connection:

```php
protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
protected $table = 'Test';
protected $primaryKey = 'TestId';
```

Everything works fine in Tinker, I get pretty instant results:

```php
App\Models\User::take(2)->get() // instant
App\Models\Test::take(2)->get() // ±0.5 second
```

When I do the same in a view, it suddenly takes 30 seconds.

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test', [
        'users' => App\Models\User::take(2)->get(), // takes milliseconds
        'test' => App\Models\Test::take(2)->get(), // takes 30 seconds
        // 'test' => DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select top 2 * from [Test]'), // also 30 sec

    ]);
});
```

When using `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` I see in the timeline: `Application` taking 30.71 seconds,
and the actual query for `App\Models\Test::take(2)->get()` taking 430 ms.
It is always 30 seconds + the time needed for the queries.

So it seems there is a 30 second timeout before the query is executed?
I installed `Telescope` and see the same thing: the request taking 30 seconds, and the query taking less than half a second.

Suggestions what is happening?

**Update**: here is the simplified test, with the same result, which rules out Eloquent/JS/view related issues.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    dd( DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select top 2 * from [Test]') );
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's not related to your backend nor database. I'm guessing that you're using some kind of cdn or one of your css or js takes too long to load.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the backend. When I don't run the `Test` query there's no 30 sec delay. When I cache the query there's no 30 sec delay. The view is a stripped HTML page, just a div with @foreach.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in the `config\database.php`.
My config has separate read+write urls, so I can easily disable write access.
It timed out on the dummy write URL (even though it was not being used).

When I changed it to `null` everything was fine.

Interesting that Tinker (or a closure command) did not have a problem with it and Route did.

```
            // 'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'read' => [
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => null // explicitly disable writing
            ],
```